# I keep getting a compiler error saying css no valid after double and triple checking I can't seem to find the error

Tags: sass

```
@import '_colors.scss';
@import '_fonts.scss';
@import '_urls.scss';
@import '_mixins.scss';

html, body 
  height: 100%


body 
  display: grid
  font-family: $clickme, $clickme-fallback;
  color: $color;


a 
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;


.cta 
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 19px 22px;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  &:before
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 28px;
    background: rgba($primary,.5);
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    transition: all .3s ease;


  span 
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: .25em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align: middle;


  svg 
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    fill: none;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
    stroke: $color;
    stroke-width: 2;
    transform: translateX(-5px);
    transition: all .3s ease;


  &:hover 
    &:before
      width: 100%;
      background: rgba($primary,1);


    svg
      transform: translateX(0);


  &:active 
    transform: scale(.96);
```

I am trying to get to compile without any error codes and it appears that after several attempts it is not working I have tried several different methods and error codes keep appearing that no valid css is after every line will some one please help this is a final project and I need help getting it ready by monday night.

Comment: Presumably the errors are pointing you at the offending lines?

Comment: If I define the necessary variables and fix the indentation, the SASS in the question doesn't raise any errors. Of course, I left out the imports.

Comment: Nobody cares if this is your final project or if you have some deadline. Please remove such unneeded information from your question. Also, you don't need to say "will some one please help". Every single question on SO, is by definition a request for help.

Comment: try removing all semi-colons

Comment: Are you using SASS or SCSS? This file is a mixture of both. Doesnt work that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove .scss from the import statements.

If your file has .scss extension then you have to use brackets and semi colons but if it has .sass extensoon then you have to remove these semi colons

Then compile your file to css with any software like prepros or use to the sass command line.
Remember to link the css file to your html document.

Hope that it works

Comment: I tried was you suggested at it says invalid CSS after 'mixing' it expected at-rule or selector and there wasn't one. Have you ever seen this before?

Comment: No, I don't remember seeing any error like this. Sorry for replying late